# Removing a comment from Fortify

Tags: fortify

I'm working in the fortify web app and I need to remove a comment I posted by mistake on one of the issues. I can't find anyway of doing this, does anyone know how its done or if its even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to remove a comment is to remove it from the database.  If you have the access, you can find the particular comment by:

```
Select * From AuditComment
```

Once you've found it, you can remove it by using the following :

```
Delete From AuditComment Where issue_id = <IssueID here> and seqNumber = <Sequence Number here>
```

*BE CAREFUL*  You've been warned.

Comment: I don't know of *any* database for the Fortify software that could be utilized for this.

Comment: No need to downvote when you don't know what you are talking about.  If he is using the web app (as he stated!), then he is using either Fortify 360 or Fortify SSC.  Both of them are Java web apps with a Flash front end and a database back end.

Here are some links for your consumption:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957929/difference-betwwen-fortify-sca-vs-fortify-ssc
http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/fortify-software-security-tracking/

Comment: To minimize risk of disaster, you should add `LIMIT 1` to the query

Answer (score 1):

If you have data base access of fortify SSC then you can edit or delete the content , otherwise you can not edit the comments on Enterprise Fortify SSC portal.